# Find a polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $\leq 2$ such that $\phi^4=q(\phi )$.

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

**The Question**

Suppose $\phi : V\rightarrow V$ has minimal polynomial $x^3+2x+1$. Find a polynomial $q(x)$ of degree $\leq 2$ such that $\phi^4=q(\phi )$.

---

**My Questions**

I'm a bit stuck on starting this one, but I think the two following questions will help get me on my way.  A short hint is all I need!

1. What does $\phi^4$ mean?
2. How does the minimal polynomial help me here?

---

**Thanks everyone!**

Comment: $\phi^4=\phi\circ\phi\circ\phi\circ\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $\phi$ satisfies its minimal polynomial, therefore $\phi^3 = -2 \phi - I\,$, so $\,\phi^4 = \;\cdots$

Comment: Does that mean $\phi^3+2\phi+I=0$?

Comment: @ThyArtisMath Right, that's where $\phi^3 = -2 \phi - I\,$ follows from.

Comment: It just clicked!  Thanks!